# Conversion of fine organic surface mesh to a few patches of NURBS

Tags: mesh, nurbs

I have a very fine mesh (STL) of some organic shapes (e.g., a bone) and would like to convert it to a few patches of NURBS, which will be much smoother with reasonable simplification.

I can do this manually with Solidworks ScanTo3D function, but it is not scriptable. It's a pain when I need to do hundreds of them.

Would there be a way to automate it, e.g., with some open source libraries available? I am perfectly fine with quite some loss in accuracy. I use mainly Python, but I don't mind if it is in other languages and I can work my way around it.

Note that one thing I'd like to avoid is to convert an STL of 10,000 triangles to a NURBS with 10,000 patches. I'd like to automatically (programmatically, could be with some parameter tunings) divide the mesh into a few patches and then fit it. Again, I'm perfect fine with quite some loss in accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Converting an arbitrary mesh to nurbs is not easy in general. What is a good nurbs surface for a given mesh depends on the use case. Do you want to manually edit the nurbs surface afterwards? Should symmetric structures or other features be recognized and represented correctly in the nurbs body? Is it important to keep the volume of the body? Are there boundary lines that should not be simplified as they change the appearance or angles that must be kept?

If you just want to smooth the mesh or reduce the amount of vertices there are easier ways like **mesh reduction** and **mesh smoothing**.

If you require your output to be nurbs there are different methods leading to different topologies and approximations like indicated above. A commonly used method for object simplification is to register the mesh to some handmade prototype and then perform some smaller changes to shape the specific instance. If there are for example several classes of shapes like bones, hearts, livers etc. it might be possible to model a prototype nurbs body for each class once which defines the average appearance and topology of that organ. Each instance of a class can then be converted to a nurbs by fitting the prototype to that instance. As the topology is fixed the optimization problem is reduced to the problem where we need to find the control points that approximate the mesh with the smallest error.Disadvantage of this method is that you have to create a prototype for each class. The advantage is that the topology will be nice and easily editable.

Another approach would be to first smooth the mesh and reduce the polygon count (there are libraries available for mesh reduction) and then simply converting each triangle/ quad to a nurbs patch (like the Rhino [MeshToNurb Command](https://wiki.mcneel.com/rhino/meshtonurb)). This method should be easier to implement but the resulting nurbs body could have an ugly topology.

If one of this methods is applicable really depends on what you want to do with your transformed data.